# por que me tira este error Expected type 'object'. Found 'string PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli, poo, php7, pdo

Tengo una clase conexion de tipo PDO llamada model.php la cual es la siguiente:

```
<?php
class model{
    /**
     * Las funciones de PDO "Data Objects of PHP", son exclusivas para
     * trabajar con programacion orientada a objetos.
     */
    private $server  = "localhost";
    private $port    = "3308";
    private $user    = "root";
    private $pass    = "";
    private $database= "ctrlempleados";
    private $connect;

    /**
     * A continuacion la Funcion que nos permitira
     * la coneccion, por metodo de PDO.
     */
    public function __construct(){
        $ConnectionString = "mysql:host=".$this->server.";port=".$this->port.";dbname=".$this->database.";charset=utf8";
        
        try{
            $this->connect = new PDO($ConnectionString, $this->user, $this->pass);
            /**
             * En la linea de codigo anterior, se creo
             * una nueva instancia del objeto PDO, que nos
             * funcionara, para ejecutar nuestro $ConnectionString,
             * mientras lo concatenamos con el resto de datos, que serian
             * user y pass.
             */
            $this->connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            /**
             * La linea de codigo anterior hace posible que los errores
             * de PDO se puedan mostrar en pantalla, si es que alguno
             * se presenta.
             */
            echo 'Conexion Exitosa';
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $this->connect = 'Error de Conexion.';
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
            /**
             * Si en dado caso se encuentra un error o excepcion,
             * se procede a poder imprimirlo e pantalla, con las lineas
             * de codigo anteriores.
             */
        }//finally {
            /**
             * Si todo salio exitosamente
             * la conexion se cerrara automaticamente
             * con este finally.
             */
            //$this->connect = null;
        //}
    }

    public function connector(){
        return $this->connect;
        /**
         * Funcion que nos servira para llamar nuestra coneccion,
         * en donde sea requerida.
         */
    }
}
```

y tambien tengo esta otra clase, la cual llame user_model.php, la cual es la siguiente:

```
<?php
/**
 * Este autoloader nos sirve para llamar exactamente a las
 * clases que nuestras funciones o clase vallan a necesitar para
 * funcionar.
 */
require_once ('loader/autoload.php');

class user_model extends model{

    private $UMUserName;
    private $UMPassword;
    private $UMEmail;
    private $UMTelephone;
    private $UMDPI;
    private $UMSalary;
    private $UMConnector;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->UMConnector = new model();
        $this->UMConnector = $this->UMConnector->connector();
        /**
         * llamamos a nuestra conexion con este constructor.
         */
    }

    public function Insert_User(string $UserName, string $Password, string $Email, string $Telefono, string $DPI, float $Salary){

        $this->UMUserName = $UserName;
        $this->UMPassword = $Password;
        $this->UMEmail    = $Email;
        $this->UMTelephone= $Telefono;
        $this->UMDPI      = $DPI;
        $this->UMSalary   = $Salary;

        /**
         * El metodo de PDO, nos ofrece la idea de tratar todas nuestras sentencias,
         * como preparadas, esto nos ayuda en especifico a disminuir
         * riesgos de una inyeccion SQL.
         */
        $SQL ="INSERT INTO `users` (`idUsuario`, `UserN`, `PassW`, `Email`, `Telefono`, `DPI`, `Salario`) 
               VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

        $Insert    = $this->UMConnector->prepare($SQL);
        /** Error 1
         * En la linea de codigo anterior, preparamos nuestra sentencia
         * para poder ejecutarla con nuestra conexion despues.
         */
        $arrData   = array($this->UMUserName, $this->UMPassword, $this->UMEmail, $this->UMTelephone, $this->UMDPI, $this->UMSalary);
        /**
         * Preparamos el array que se va a enviar con nuestra sentencia ya preparada.
         */
        $resInsert = $Insert->execute($arrData);
        /**
         * Ejecutamos la sentencia para poder ya ingresar seguramente
         * nuestros nuevos registros ya a la Base de Datos.
         */
        $idInsert  = $this->UMConnector->__construct->lastInsertId();//Error2
        return $idInsert;
        /**
         * Ya luego devolvemos el ultimo id agregado con las
         * instrucciones anteriores.
         */
    }
}
```

Ahora explico que es lo que ocurre, lo que paso es que luego de crear en la clase model la funcion connector() e instanciarla en la clase user_model() mas especificamente en mi funcion __construct(), me arrojo un error en las lineas 44 y 58 de la clase user_model(), el cual dice que $this->UMConnector: Expected type 'object'. Found 'string, queria saber por que me ocurre esto y si podia arreglarlo... Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Si prestas atención, cuando la creación de `new PDO()` falla, en el `catch` estas asignado `$this->connect = 'Error de Conexion.';`, en otras palabras, solo si la conexión a la DB falla `$this->connect` es una cadena.

Answer (score 1):

Al contructor de `user_model` como primer línea llama al [constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php) de la que hereda; es decir:

```
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(); // Línea a agregar
        $this->UMConnector = new model();
        $this->UMConnector = $this->UMConnector->connector();
        /**
         * llamamos a nuestra conexion con este constructor.
         */
    }
```

Comment: el error aun no se quita luego de agregar eso...

Comment: Al hacer `parent::__construct();`, las lineas debajo así como están carecen de sentido. En su lugar podrías hacer ser algo como `$this->UMConnector = $this->connector();`

Comment: @Marcos realize las lineas de codigo que me dijiste, pero el error sigue igual, no lo reconoce como un objeto, sino como un string...

Comment: @MarenCarlo no tiene caso extender/heredar una clase si no usaras esta; dentro estas creando el `model` como pone @Marcos ya queda igual; incluso con `$this->connect` ya haces referencia a los mismo y de ahi agregar `->prepare`, `->execute` y demás. Fijate que el insert tiene 7 parámetro y solo envías 6.

Comment: Listo, coloque todo como me dijeron, pero el error sigue ahi.... no se que podria ser... ya arregle la sentencia y elimine las lineas de __construct(), para solo dejarle una... pero el error sigue ahi...

Comment: @MarenCarlo, como te comente antes, el problema es que la conexión a la DB falla.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre solucion, perdon por preguntar por un error tan basico, pero lo que sucedio es que confundi las variables, ahora para corregirse y que funcione bien, debe quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
        public function __construct(){
        $this->UMConnector = new model();
        $this->UMConnector = $this->model->connector();//aca llamaba a la variable, en vez de llamar a la clase.
        /**
         * llamamos a nuestra conexion con este constructor.
         */
    }
```

Comment: De todos modos eso no tiene sentido. Si `user_model` extiende de `model`  lo que tendrías que hacer es llamar a `parent::construct()`

Comment: Además de que no tiene sentido sobrescribir la variable UMConnect

Comment: No tengo la menor idea de por que... pero funciona, le comente por ahora que sera solo para pruebas... pero luego lo cambiare, solo por asegurarme que no vaya a fallar nada luego....